# Anonymous special character present with a string in PHP

Tags: php, linux

I have a web service that contains a read operation from a text file.

This is my code:

```
$text_file = "/var/www/list".$ebookId.".txt";
```

`$ebookId` is generated dynamically.

```
$myfile = fopen($text_file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

When I read this file, I couldn't get output. Then, I echo `$text_file` using my PHP script.
There is a special character like this presented.

```
$text_file = "/var/www/list/1234.txtij/";
```

This code working perfectly in my local machine. When I upload this on an Apache Linux Server, then this error happens.

Comment: You're saying the actual line of code has changed to read like this? `$text_file    = "/var/www/list".$ebookId.".txtij";`

Comment: The actual code is like that. when i look in to ios console there is a two letter word displaying

Comment: Try creating a new file and do `$myfile = fopen($text_file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");`, if it works something else is interfering.

Comment: @deepusankar, can you just edit the code to correct it?

Comment: @Jonathan i just edited the code

Comment: When you say "special character like this" do you mean exactly 'ij' or something that looks like 'ij'??

Comment: @deepusankar, I was not referring to editing your post. I was talking about editing your actual code to remove the `ij`. We're kind of confused over what the problem is.

Comment: i think the character you are seeing is this: 
ĳ
&#307;
&#x133;
Lowercase IJ Ligature
if so you need to make sure you are using uft-8 everywhere!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$text_file = "/var/www/list/".$ebookId.".txt";` (note the `/` after `list`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_htmlcodes.htm

As taken as part of a table, 'ĳ' is indeed a special character:

`Char | Friendly Code | Numerical Code | Description`

`ĳ    | &#307;        | &#x133;        | Lowercase IJ Ligature`

This is an encoding issue, make sure you are using the same encoding everywhere.

Comment: how i remove this from my page. i can't see in my page